# Testing Vue components methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I am starting with **Vue.js** and is really hard to find documentation about **Unit Test**.

I am trying to test components `methods` and builtin stuff as `ready()`. I can call those correctly but they internally have references to `this` object and `this` context is lost during testing time.

**error**

`TypeError: this.$on is not a function`

**spec.js**

```
import Vue      from 'vue';
import Partners from 'components/main/partner/Partners';

describe.only('Partners.vue', () => {
  it('should render with mocked partners', (cb) => {
    Partners.ready(); // I get an error here because ready() is calling inside: this.$on(...)

    cb(null);
  });
});
```

**component.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'Partners',

  data() {
    return { };
  },

  methods: {
    get() {
      // ...
    }
  },
  ready() {
    this.$on('confirm', (confirm) => {
      // ...
    });

    this.get();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think ready() is depreciated along with Vue 1.0. Consider upgrading to Vue 2 (where mounted() replaces ready()).

To test your component, you need to initialize your component and a Vue instance, (and usually mount it, depending what you are doing).

Using the vue-webpack template (which uses Vue 2):

```
var ctor = Vue.extend(Partners)
var vm = new ctor()
vm.$mount()
```

now you can do things like vm.method(), and vm.mount() will automatically be called, etc.